# Como puedo ingresar un "." en mi calculadora

Tags: android, kotlin, intellij-idea

¡Buenas tardes!, quisiera un poco de ayuda para mi código, debo crear una calculadora, lo cual según mi parecer esta acabado, solo por un punto, al momento de ingresar el "." decimal, requiero que tenga una validación para que pueda ingresar otro después de una signo, la sea suma, resta, multiplicación y división. Pero no pude lograrlo, y también aprovechar de sus conocimientos para un detalle al momento de ingresar los números a mi texto, que cada 3 dígitos se muestre "," ya que esta calculadora esta diseñada para un publico niño/adolescente. Aquí dejo el código:

//Muchas Gracias de Antemano

```
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.DialogInterface
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import com.caceres.calculadora.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import org.mariuszgromada.math.mxparser.Expression
import kotlin.math.ln

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private var texto_resultado: TextView? = null
    private var texto_operacion: TextView? = null
    private val MAX_FONT_SIZE = 56f
    private val MIN_FONT_SIZE = 20f
    private val MAX_LENGTH = 75
    private lateinit var exponente2: Button
    private lateinit var exponente3: Button


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        texto_resultado = findViewById(R.id.text_ing_op)
        texto_operacion = findViewById(R.id.text_ing_op2)
        exponente2 = findViewById(R.id.btn_expo2)
        exponente2.setOnClickListener {
            if (texto_operacion?.text?.lastOrNull()?.isDigit() == true) { // Verifica si hay un número antes de agregar el exponente
                texto_operacion?.append("^2")
            }
        }
        exponente3 = findViewById(R.id.btn_expo3)
        exponente3.setOnClickListener {
            if (texto_operacion?.text?.lastOrNull()?.isDigit() == true) { // Verifica si hay un número antes de agregar el exponente
                texto_operacion?.append("^3")
            }
        }
    }

    fun press(view: View) {
        var texto: String = texto_operacion?.text.toString()
        val boton: String = (view as Button).text.toString()

        if (boton == "." && (texto.isEmpty() || texto.contains("."))) {
            return
        }
        if (texto.length >= MAX_LENGTH) {
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            builder.setMessage("Se ha alcanzado el límite máximo de caracteres.")
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null)
            builder.show()
            return
        }
        if (boton in listOf("+", "-", "×", "÷","%") && (texto.isEmpty() || texto.takeLast(1) in listOf("+", "-", "×", "÷","%"))) {
            return
        }

        texto_operacion?.text = texto + boton
        adjustFontSize()
    }

    fun borrarUltimo(view:View){
        val texto: String = texto_operacion?.text.toString()
        if(texto.length ==1)
            texto_operacion?.text="0"
        else
            texto_operacion?.text = texto.subSequence(0, texto.length -1)
    }

    fun borrarTodo(view:View) {
        texto_operacion?.setText("")
        texto_resultado?.setText("0")
    }

    fun borrarOperacion(view:View) {
        val textor: String = texto_resultado?.text.toString()
        texto_resultado?.setText("0")
    }

    private fun adjustFontSize() {
        val textLength = texto_operacion?.text?.length ?: 0
        val currentSize = texto_operacion?.textSize ?: MIN_FONT_SIZE
        val desiredSize = when {
            textLength < 10 -> MAX_FONT_SIZE
            textLength < 27 -> MAX_FONT_SIZE - 15
            textLength < 35 -> MAX_FONT_SIZE - 25
            else -> MAX_FONT_SIZE - 35
        }

        val newSize = if (desiredSize < MIN_FONT_SIZE) MIN_FONT_SIZE else desiredSize

        if (currentSize != newSize) {
            texto_operacion?.textSize = newSize
        }
    }
    fun calcular(view: View) {
        val texto: String = texto_operacion?.text.toString()
        val resultado: Double = Expression(texto).calculate()
        if (resultado.isNaN()) {
            texto_resultado?.text = "Error"
        } else {
            val resultadoTexto = if (resultado == resultado.toLong().toDouble()) {
                resultado.toLong().toString()
            } else if (resultado.toString().length > 9) {
                String.format("%.2e", resultado)
            } else {
                resultado.toString()
            }
            texto_resultado?.text = resultadoTexto
        }
    }
    fun cambiarSigno(view: View) {
        val texto = texto_operacion?.text.toString()
        if (texto.isEmpty()) {
            return
        }

        val primerCaracter = texto[0]
        if (primerCaracter == '-') {
            texto_operacion?.text = texto.substring(1)
        } else {
            texto_operacion?.text = "-$texto"
        }
    }
    private fun String.contains(s: String, s1: String, s2: String, s3: String): Boolean {
        return this.contains(s) || this.contains(s1) || this.contains(s2) || this.contains(s3)
    }
}
```

Espero poder entender mejor la lógica de programación y las herramientas de Kotlin.